# get current row number with column number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text. Now I want if my text matched with any of column value then my method return that row and column number. My current code reads only column number, but I cant understand how can I get row number.

Sample table:

```js
var index = $('tr td').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == 'Dhaka';
}).index();
console.log(index);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Rion</td>
    <td>Bogra</td>
    <td>34</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hasib</td>
    <td>Dhaka</td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If I give "Dhaka" as my given text then my code return column 1 but I need also row number as 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `el.closest('tr').index()` for the *row number* and as you already have, `el.index()` as the *column number* - see demo below:

```js
var el = $('tr td').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'Dhaka';
  });
console.log(el.index(), el.closest('tr').index());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Rion</td>
    <td>Bogra</td>
    <td>34</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hasib</td>
    <td>Dhaka</td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: In table(3,2), how i get column 3 and row 2 value?

Comment: (0,0) (row,  column) could not found.it's show (-1,-1).how i solve it?

Comment: @golammoktadir 'Rion' prints out as (0,0) and there is no (3,2) in this table as the indices start from 0.